# how do I add a pandas object (e.g. DataFrame) to a group within an HDF file?

Tags: pandas, hdf5

Suppose I have an HDF5 file (myHDF.h5) with a hierarchy of groups, something like:

```
/root/groupA
     /groupB
```

Now I want to add a `DataFrame` (myFrame) to the groupA (along with some other objects such as dictionaries). How do I do that? If I open my HDF.h5 with `pandas.io.HDFStore`:

```
store = pandas.io.HDFStore('myHDF.h5')
```

and then try:

```
store['groupA']['myFrame'] = myFrame
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: Attribute 'pandas_type' does not exist in node: '/groupA'
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

this is enabled as of version 0.10.0

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hierarchical-keys

Answer (score 0):

Currently pandas does not support hierarchical paths as you specified.

There is an open github issue about this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13

I'm not sure when we will get around to adding this feature, would more than welcome a pull request if you're interested in completing the skeleton code that's in the issue discussion.